# How to pull the wordpress.org code

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I was given an existing wordpress.org site . 
What I wanted to do is to create a local copy of that site on my machine. How will I do that?

Comment: Did you mean WordPress.org, or WordPress.com? ie is it a WordPress blog hosted by WordPress.com, or is it a WordPress blog hosted by some other 3rd party hosting company?

Comment: Looking at some of your comments (eg not familiar with FTP), it sounds like you're not especially technical (not meant to come across as an insult!) and hence you're going to have a hard time getting a local copy of WP up and running on your local machine (as that is also quite technical).  Perhaps edit your question to explain what it is you want to ultimately achieve, and we may be able to help you with that instead?

Answer (score 3):

The [latest version of wordpress is available for download here](http://wordpress.org/download/).

But if you want to look at the specific code on your site, or copy it locally, then you'll want to use an FTP tool (eg FileZilla) to connect to the server hosting your site.

(And obviously you'll need to know the FTP credentials for that server).

You'll need to connect to the database to get an export of it (eg using phpMyAdmin) from your host's eg cPanel if it's being used (and again, you'll need the relevant cPanel creds).  Refer to [WordPress Codex - Backing up your database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database).

You'll need Apache, mySQL, and PHP installed on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Access the website via ftp and download the wordpress folder. After access the database administration panel and download a copy of the database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ftp. How will I do that?

Comment: Search the topic using Google. This is a very large matter to be discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the site's server, you need to:
1. Back up that site's database through the site's admin panel
2. Download the entire webroot of the wordpress installation (use `mget /remote/directory` in FTP)
3. Ensure that you have a database set up with the right credentials. In MySQL:
`CREATE USER 'name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';`
`CREATE DATABASE dbname;`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname TO 'name@'localhost';`
4. Install wordpress into a web directory
5. Edit the `wp-config.php` file in the now-installed webroot to match your database user, password and name, as well as hostname if needed.
6. Use the backup you obtained in the first step to restore the database from the admin panel
7. Restore all media from the second step by moving files into the webroot and avoiding all overwrites (easy in an FTP client. not so easy manually.)

Comment: I'll be getting the code from wordpress itself which is already up and running online. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure that you have access to the site for mirroring? If so, in the admin panel (`wp-admin.php`), there is an option to download a copy of the database.

Comment: Yes, I can access the admin panel (wp-admin). In what specific link should I click to download a copy of the database?

Comment: [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) could be of some help.